# Taking control over Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, png

Is there any way to take control over the browser, from outside of it? I want to use IE to save my SVG as PNG as it could render it properly. As far as I know, there is no CMD argument for such thing.

Thanks

Comment: Please describe your issue with more detail like how you are trying to download the SVG? Which site you are using for download? If it is public site you can share the URL and steps to produce the issue. If it is private site than please try to provide sample code which can produce the issue. If we can produce the issue than we can understand it properly and can try to suggest you the possible ways to fulfill your requirement. To take a control of IE from outside you can use VBA IE Automation or selenium web driver to automate IE object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. VBA IE Automation is the tool I needed. But the problem is now that I can't set the file type. When you right-click over the SVG in IE, you can select to save it as PNG in the dialog box. I can make VBA download the file but nothing more.

Comment: As I informed you before, it will be better if you provide any sample code. Only description is not helpful. Try to provide HTML and the VBA code which you tried till now. We can try to test it to see whether there is any possible way save the SVG as PNG using your code.

Comment: save the file as a `.svg` and then convert to a `.png`?